# how can gimbal lock happen?

Tags: graphics, 3d, rotation

i was reading about gimbal lock. 
it happens when there is as parent child kind of heirarchy in rotation axes. like if heirarchy is x-y-z then rotating x affects y and z, rotating y affects z only and not x, rotating z affects no other axes.

But how i was visualizing is when y rotates(middle axis), which is mostly shown to cause gimbal lock x and z should not align , but what if they stay 90 degree apart and basically all rotations dont affect mutual orthogonality of the axes?

What is the name of second kind of rotation if it is there?

Comment: I don't completely understand your question. But if you have a situation where the rotation axes don't align, then you don't have gimbal lock. If none of the rotations affect mutual orthogonality, then you can only rotate the outer-most ring as all others would change orthogonality.

Comment: yes @NicoSchertler i just wanted to know what is that system called so that i can compare with gimbal system and why are we even taught about gimbal system. Is it more efficient or what ?